# WSO2-IS-5.0.0-SP01 Download Location

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am trying to replicate an existing WSO2 Identity Server setup. It is WSO2 IS 5.0.0 + SP01.

I can no longer find the download link for SP01 and am not at liberty to upgrade the WSO2 IS version in the near future. I do understand that there were multiple patches which were rolled into SP01 and hence doing the same manually would be time consuming.

Is there a download location or a matching patch which is similar to SP01?

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link to download service pack
http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/identity-server/5.0.0/service-pack/WSO2-IS-5.0.0-SP01.zip

Comment: I get a 403 forbidden when I try this link. An account is probably necessarr, where can i create such account?

Comment: I created a user account on wso2.com, but even if I'm logged in on this user account, i still get a 403

Comment: @yohann.martineau try adding the referer header - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Using wget/curl and adding the --referer (doesn't work w/o it) option seems to do the trick and creating an account is not necessary:

```
wget --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download" http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/identity-server/5.0.0/service-pack/WSO2-IS-5.0.0-SP01.zip
```